# Display a favicon in a Chrome extension newtab page using manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I have recently migrated my chrome extension to manifest v3 using this guide:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/

The v3 manifest.json file no longer supports using `chrome://favicon/`. Looking through the documentation I could not find an alternative. There were some articles I found that said it might be moved to a new `favicon` permission and be available under the `google.favicon` namespace. However they were all older and speculative, I tried these speculations to no avail.

Comment: There's no solution as MV3 is still half-broken. Until favicon API is added just keep using MV2. If you really want MV3 for whatever reason, use an external service like google/duckduckgo favicons retriever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new API was just released as part of Chrome 104!

To use it, first add the `favicon` permission to your manifest.json:

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": ["favicon"],
    ...
}
```

Then you can load the favicon using your chrome extension's id, for example:

```
const faviconSrc = `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/_favicon/?pageUrl=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&size=32`;
```

Answer (score 3):

it seems like they forget to build [this api](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104102), you can star this issue on the page or leave a comment to tell them.

Answer (score 0):

[Issue 104102: Create a new API permission for access to favicons](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104102) was fixed on June 13, 2022.

[chrome://favicon Replacement for Extensions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ksvSq1zF-9jYSfGOvNluyoTV0Ud9xl6r9HiAKONqmz8/edit#) document mentions the API:

```
var faviconUrl = new URL('chrome-extension://<id>/_favicon');
faviconUrl.searchParams.append('page_url', 'http://example.com');
let image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = faviconUrl.href;
// src is 'chrome-extension://<id>/?page_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F'
```

Note that there's a mistake on the last line. It should be:

```
// src is 'chrome-extension://<id>/_favicon?page_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F'
```

Unfortunately, I still hasn't been able to get this API working on Chrome Canary 105.0.5174.0, which should include the changes from the resolved bug already. I'm getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED` errors.